# Replace whitespace from txt file and special character

Tags: php, regex

I'm new to php and sql stuff and I struggle at the moment by convert or replace whitespaces to semicolon.
Below you can se my txt file and my php code at the moment:

`Dst    47.5323    47.8000     0.3000    -0.3000    -0.2677             ----      AD47_8`
`Dst    44.3483    44.8450     0.3000    -0.3000    -0.4967    -0.1967  <<<<      ID44_845`
  `Y    -2.3005     2.3090     0.0500    -0.0500    -0.0085                -      S2_309_1`
`Wkl    54.7679°   55.0000°    0.1000°   -0.1000°   -0.2321°   -0.1321°  <<<<     W55°_1`

```
<?php
$file_content = file("messdaten.txt");

foreach($file_content as $line){
    $line = explode("\n", $line);
    $line = preg_replace( "(\s+)",";",$line);
    $line = str_replace("°","",$line);
    print_r($line);
}
?>
```

my result is this:

`Array ( [0] => Dst;47.5323;47.8000;0.3000;-0.3000;-0.2677;----;AD47_8; )`
`Array ( [0] => Dst;44.3483;44.8450;0.3000;-0.3000;-0.4967;-0.1967;<<<<;ID44_845; )`
`Array ( [0] => ;Y;-2.3005;2.3090;0.0500;-0.0500;-0.0085;-;S2_309_1; )` 
`Array ( [0] => Wkl;54.7679�;55.0000�;0.1000�;-0.1000�;-0.2321�;-0.1321�;<<<<;W55�_1 )`

The problem is that the txt file has 9 "columns". At the moment i can only remove the whitespace this is working good.
Did you have a idea how to split it in 9 columns seperated by semicolon and remove the ° degree symbol?
It would be also okay to have the first 5 columns and the last column.
Later i want to save it as csv and then import it to mysql.

In advance already huge thanks for your help. I hope to understand it better when I receive tips from you.

Best regards

Stefan

Comment: When you `explode` the line, `trim` it first. `$line = explode("\n", trim($line))`

Comment: Your txt file and your php script likely have different encoding so `str_replace` is not recognizing the symbol.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the trim funktion dont work, the file is ASCII formatted and i found out the whitespaces are number 32 in ASCII. Did i have to convert the data first to utf-8 and then use trim again?

Comment: I was wrong, it is an formatted ANSI file.

Comment: So try `$line = print_r(preg_split("~\s+~", str_replace("°","",trim($line))));`

Comment: Thank you very much :) its working very well

Comment: I edited your answer because it was important to encode to UTF-8 to remove degree symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```php
<?php
$file_content = file("messdaten.txt");
$file_content = array_map('utf8_encode',$file_content);
foreach($file_content as $line){
    $line = preg_split("~\s+~", str_replace("°","",trim($line)));
    print_r($line);
}
?>
```

Here,

- `trim($line)` removes the whitespace on both ends
- `str_replace("°","",...)` - removes `°` chars
- `preg_split("~\s+~", ...)` - splits by 1 or more whitespace chars.